# What is the recommended way to import PAUSE in redux-persist?

Tags: redux-persist

I am using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

One way to pause is using:

```
persistor.pause();
```

I hope to pause in my epic. What is the recommended way to import PAUSE?

```
import { PAUSE } from 'redux-persist/lib/constants';
import { PAUSE } from 'redux-persist/es/constants';
import { PAUSE } from 'redux-persist/src/constants';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got response from the redux-persist's owner Zack Story.

Right now you can use either of these three.

```
import { PAUSE } from 'redux-persist/lib/constants';
import { PAUSE } from 'redux-persist/es/constants';
import { PAUSE } from 'redux-persist/src/constants';
```

In the future, it will be

```
import { PAUSE } from 'redux-persist';
```

Please check [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/543) for the update.